# Nested if and max if statement in R error: unused argument

Tags: r, if-statement, max, maxifs

Still quite new to R and I would like to identify the biggest value of a variable within a group when an other variable is postive/negative. Specifically, `if l_diff<0`, I would like to find the biggest value of t in each group when `pos_n<0`. If `l_diff>0`, I would like to find the biggest value of t in each group when `pos_p>0`. Example data:

```
l_diff <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1)
pos_n <- c(2,2,1,-4,-2,-2,2,1,-5,4,8)
pos_p <- c(3,4,-5,6,-7,2,-3,3,2,1,4)
t <- c(5,7,3,1,6,2,7,5,3,2,1)
group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
db <- data.frame(cbind(l_diff,pos_n, pos_p, t, group))
```

Desired output:

```
cmax<- c(6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5)
```

I tried the following:

```
db<-db %>%
  group_by((group)) %>%
  mutate(ifelse(l_diff<0, t1 = max(t[pos_n<0], ifelse(l_diff>0, t1 = max(t[pos_p >0])))))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x unused argument (t1 =
> max(t[pos_n < 0], ifelse(l_diff > 0, t1 = max(t[pos_p > 0])))) i
> Input `..1` is `ifelse(...)`. i The error occurred in group 1: (group)
> = 1.

Any idea what may be wrong or any other suggestions?

Comment: The `t1 =` should be outside and you need the `no`output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ifelse`, we need to place the assignment outside, similarly, all the arguments in the `ifelse` usage must be present

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

Here, the `no` was not found in the nested second `ifelse`.  It is not an issue if we use `case_when` as by default the `TRUE ~ NA`

```
library(dplyr)
db %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(t1  = ifelse(l_diff<0,  max(t[pos_n<0]), 
                ifelse(l_diff>0,max(t[pos_p >0]), NA))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 6
#   l_diff pos_n pos_p     t group    t1
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     -1     2     3     5     1     6
# 2     -1     2     4     7     1     6
# 3     -1     1    -5     3     1     6
# 4     -1    -4     6     1     1     6
# 5     -1    -2    -7     6     1     6
# 6     -1    -2     2     2     1     6
# 7      1     2    -3     7     2     5
# 8      1     1     3     5     2     5
# 9      1    -5     2     3     2     5
#10      1     4     1     2     2     5
#11      1     8     4     1     2     5
```